# error while sharing on whatsapp from my app

Tags: android

I'am trying to share image and text from my App. Data is coming from server. My Web page link is this

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="whatsapp://send?text=Bhulne Ke Tujhe Najaane Kitne Waade Karte Hai, 
Kaise Bhulayun Tujhe Ye Sochkar Tujhe Yaad Karte Hai,
Jab Bhi Hota Hai Zikar Jamaane Me Pyar Aur Wafa Ka, 
To Tumhe Bewafa Ke Bahaane Yaad Karte Hai!
"><span class="whatsapp">&nbsp;</span></a>
```

http://way2enjoy.com/app/jokestest.php

```
if (url.startsWith("whatsapp")) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    String result = uri.getQuery().split("=")[1];
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "" + result);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + result));
    intent.setType("image/*");
    //  intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
```

but i am getting error "sharing failed please try again" . i have already given permission of storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: share the log error.

Comment: @HariRam how to get error log. i know in php but in android where the error will be ??

Comment: @HariRam can u please help ?????

Comment: @HariRam no error atall

Comment: @shabbir-dhangot can u please suggest